# Como mostrar uma imagem da base de dados numa form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Eu gostaria de saber como é que posso mostrar uma imagem da base de dados numa form no vb.net

É algo tipo o seguinte:

```
info.TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value
```

Só que essse código eu utilizo para mostrar texto da base de dados numa nova form.
Como é que posso fazer isso com uma imagem?

Comment: Tua imagem está guardada na base de dados em qual formato? Binário ou base 64?

Answer (score 0):

Se sua imagem já estiver armazenada em uma coluna oculta de seu `DataGridView1`, com tipo `Bitmap` ou `Image`, você só precisa de uma PictureBox:

```
info.PictureBox1.Image = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value
```

Como [Kaizonaro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15926/kaizonaro) disse, contudo, dependendo de como sua imagem está armazenada, você vai ter que criar o objeto `Image` na hora, com comandos adicionais, que vão variar conforme o caso (por exemplo, caso você tenha um stream binário seria de uma forma, caso um string em Base64, outra forma, etc.)